# How can I add Variables into a String?(Swift)

Tags: string, swift, variables

I want to add some variables to a string:

```
var age:Int
var pets:String
lblOutput.text = "Your"+ var pets +"is"+ var age +"years old!"
```

The both variables aren't nil. And i think this is how it worked in objective-c, wasn't it?

Thanks!

Comment: Your well documented answer is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID291), in the Apple documentation.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

In swift, string interpolation is done using `\()` within strings. Like so:

```
let x = 10
let string = "x equals \(x) and you can also put expressions here \(5*2)"
```

so for your example, do:

```
var age:Int=1
var pet:String="dog"
lblOutput.text = "Your \(pet) is \(age) years old!"
```

Comment: Thank you mate for very speedy answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can add variables to a string this way also:

```
let args = [pets, age]

let msg = String(format: "Your %@ is %@ years old", arguments: args)

print(msg)
```

Answer (score -2):

example :

```
var age = 27
var name = "George"
```

```
print("I'm \(name), My age is \(age)")

output: I'm George, My age is 27
```

you need add to back slash in front (age)

Comment: This solution has already been given by the accepted answer