# Adding a letter to a string variable in swift

Tags: swift

For example, this variable needs to add "25" after the "%" character. How can I do it?

```
var message = "cars %50 discount"
```

must be "cars %2550 discount"

Comment: Assuming you are talking about encoding a URL, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url

Comment: thanks @rmaddy , it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by replacing '%' with '%25' or whatever characters you'd like to insert after '%':

```
var message = "cars %50 discount"
message = message.replacingOccurrences(of: "%", with: "%25")
```

This approach is dangerous, check the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38869201/4763963) answer for more information and for an alternative approach.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this link provides the answer you need:
[How can I add Variables into a String?(Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671000/how-can-i-add-variables-into-a-stringswift)

For your example do:

```
var discountAmount = 2550

var message = "cars %\(discountAmount) discount"
```

(and the message prints "cars %2550 discount"